# Como saber o que deve ou não ser protegido por Criptografia em um Site?

Tags: php, segurança, arquitetura-de-software

Gostaria de saber como eu defino/sei se um site que vou desenvolver precisa ou não ser "protegido por criptografia"? Claro, excluindo os casos óbvios, como os dados do cartão em um e-commerce por exemplo.

Creio que nem todo o conteúdo de um site precisa ser criptografado, certo? Se for esse o caso, pegando como exemplo um site para um e-commerce, como eu sei o que deve ou não ser criptografado?

Julgo que nesse caso, os dados dos produtos não precisam, já que eles são acessíveis de forma pública, porém os dados pessoais dos clientes precisam ser criptografados, certo? Nesse caso, quais modelos/tipos de criptografias usar? Pois de alguma forma os funcionários da "loja virtual" possuem certo acesso aos meus dados principais (Como nome, endereço, número de celular, etc...).

O mesmo vale para um Banco, eles tem acesso as minha informações ao mesmo passo que eu também possuo. Nesse caso eles usam Criptografia RSA? Ou seja, eu posso Criptografar/Descriptografar, enquanto que eles só podem Descriptografar? Se for esse o caso, como fica o "gerenciamento das Chaves"? Elas ficam jogadas de forma "pura" no Banco, ou em um arquivo? Ou eles (não só uma Instituição Bancaria, mas qualquer Empresa) usam algum método que possibilita apenas que eles e o cliente tenham acesso as Chaves?

Em fim, como sei o que devo ou não Criptografar e como faço para ambos os lados terem acesso as informações Criptografadas quando é necessário? E nesse caso, como cuidar da Segurança das Chaves?

**Obs:** Estou ignorando os casos em que realmente as informações são Criptografadas com Criptografia de Ponta-a-Ponta, porque nesses casos, fica claro que apenas o usuário final tem acesso aos seus dados pessoais.

Comment: Não concordo que minha pergunta seja ampla demais, embora concorde que eu tenha feito mais de uma pergunta ao mesmo tempo.